# Holes in spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, topology

Suppose a take a standard 1+1 Minkowski spacetime. Then I "make a hole in it", in the sense that I remove set of points that satisfy $x^2+t^2 \leq 1$ in some inertial frame. Can the resulting object still be understood as a Minkowski spacetime, or as a relativistic spacetime more generally? If not, then why not?

Comment: Just my opinion, but wouldn’t this be more suitable on the Physics Stack Exchange?

Comment: Mathematical remarks while this is at MSE: By analogy, suppose we remove a closed disk from a Euclidean plane. Is the result still a Euclidean plane? (No.) Is it a flat surface? (Yes, but not geodesically complete.) <> The point is, it may be necessary to sharpen the definitions in question to get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: By removing the set of points, you have not changed the metric, so it is still a Minkowski spacetime. All you've done is made it a spacetime with geodesics that abruptly end instead of going on forever. If such a manifold were not still a spacetime, then our actual universe fails to be a spacetime either, since every geodesic in it when extended about 13.5 billions years into the past from our frame-of-reference also abruptly ends. (If our definition of "spacetime" did not allow this, then we would have had to redefine "spacetime".)

Answer (score 4):

For a spacetime to be Minkowski, it must be flat, and the global chart map needs to be $(x,t)$ such that the line element takes the form $ds^2 = t^2 - x^2$. This does not make any reference to the presence of holes. A spacetime with holes can still be Minkowski, except that it will be [geodesically incomplete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18254/ways-in-which-a-manifold-can-be-geodesically-incomplete).

Additionally, if geodesics are allowed to originate from the boundary of the hole, then the spacetime also loses predictability in the region that lies within the light cone spanned for by the null geodesics that originate from the hole.